# $_GET getting cut off on server but works on local

Tags: linux, centos, php

Our developers all work on their local machines and we have an issue where $_GET is getting cut off on the server but not on the local. (MAC, Apache/MySQL build -NOT MAMP)

Is there a setting on CENTOS for this? Same code, same database on both

Here is the correct URI

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /mapp/index/redirectToCart?productID=732&product=732&related_product=&qty=
```

From the server (CentOS release 6.5 (Final))

```
  Array
    (
        [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
        [HTTPS] => on
        [SSL_TLS_SNI] => www.mydomain.com
        [SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU] => Domain Control Validated
        [SSL_SERVER_S_DN_CN] => mydomain.com
   ......
        [HTTP_HOST] => www.mydomain.com
        [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
        [HTTP_COOKIE] => frontend=rb7ehmse7lfrile9q0o5gkj0h1; CATEGORY_INFO=%5B%5D; LAST_CATEGORY=3403; VIEWED_PRODUCT_IDS=732; _ga=GA1.2.549931750.1410525313; _gat=1
        [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.6 Safari/537.78.2
        [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us
        [HTTP_REFERER] => http://www.mydomain.com/apw-wyott-cheesemelter-countertop-36-wide-ea.html
        [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
        [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
        [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
        [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
        [SERVER_NAME] => www.mydomain.com
        [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.2.5.5
        [SERVER_PORT] => 443
        [REMOTE_ADDR] => [removed]
        [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/mydomain.com/staging/current/
        [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@mydomain.com
        [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/mydomain.com/staging/current/index.php
        [REMOTE_PORT] => 15070
        [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
        [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
        [QUERY_STRING] => 
        [REQUEST_URI] => /index.php/mapp/index/redirectToCart
        [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
        [PATH_INFO] => /mapp/index/redirectToCart
        [PATH_TRANSLATED] => redirect:/index.php/index/redirectToCart
        [PHP_SELF] => /index.php/mapp/index/redirectToCart
        [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1410543560.059
        [REQUEST_TIME] => 1410543560
    )
```

From local

```
   Array
(
    [REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
    [HTTP_HOST] => fsss.local
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => _ga=GA1.2.2052654414.1410539051; CART=1af3799f2a75e89cb32e44ba38ab155d; CUSTOMER=37853b37ccdeca3c78270537e91e1f58; CUSTOMER_INFO=d65ce707afe805e0549ec6b9f8c68708; frontend=ru4dl80guqbho0h979srj4str0; persistent_shopping_cart=zblxqfEcDKDmSbs8o2mJFqoOUv56aFRabxIlnqEfL2WNukdAzp; VIEWED_PRODUCT_IDS=732
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.6 Safari/537.78.2
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us
    [HTTP_REFERER] => http://client.local/apw-wyott-cheesemelter-countertop-36-wide-ea.html
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [PATH] => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.4.24 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.40 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.16.2
    [SERVER_NAME] => client.local
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /Volumes/Data/prjs/sources/mydomain/
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [revoved]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /Volumes/Data/prjs/sources/mydomain/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57218
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => productID=732&product=732&related_product=&qty=0
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /mapp/index/redirectToCart
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => productID=732&product=732&related_product=&qty=0
    [REQUEST_URI] => /mapp/index/redirectToCart?productID=732&product=732&related_product=&qty=0
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1410543740.533
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1410543740
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either a setting with Apache/httpd.conf and PHP/php.ini. In CentOS you can either configure your php.ini file or I'm not sure if you're also using cPanel where you can configure the entire set on the cPanel WHM User Interface panel.

I would look at how CentOS/PHP configuration is configured in order to get that resolved. CentOS is a little strange when it comes to these things vs. Ubuntu.

One of biggest reason could be that in your app CentOS treats REQUEST_URI path 
differently from your app config settings. Not to sounds negative, Mac and CentOS are completely different. You'll run into issues for sure.

Comment: No cPanel - Strait Centos install

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use this:

```
<?php
function request_URI() {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    }
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = request_URI();
```

?>